# How can I remove a row from a flextable?

Tags: r, flextable

Given a `flextable` object how can I remove a row from it? For the below example the question more specifically is: How can I turn `flexiris_six` into `flexiris_five` without having to use different raw data?

```r
library(flextable) # version 0.9.2

flexiris_six <- flextable(head(iris))
flexiris_five <- flextable(head(iris, 5))
```

Comment: I am not aware of such a kind of functionality! So modify your data frame and create a flextable thereafter! See: <https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/blob/HEAD/R/augment_rows.R>

Comment: At the time of TarJae's comment the statement was correct. However, there is now a correct answer below because there was an update in `flextable 0.9.4` adding this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the function `delete_rows` in flextable for that.
Just try this:

```
library(flextable) # version 0.9.4

flexiris_six <- flextable(head(iris))

flexiris_five <- flexiris_six %>%
  delete_rows(i = 6, part = "body")
```

Comment: Works! Thank you for bringing the solution after the addition was made to `flextable` in version `0.9.4`. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flextable/news/news.html